# Windows Application Forms Parent-Child relationship using primary-foreign key relationship filter

Tags: c#

I am newbie to Windows Application Forms.
I have three tables as a source data to my three Forms. Patient Form is the Parent Form, it has primary key ID. Consultation Form is a Child Form which has ID as foreign key. A Patient has multiple consultations at different dates therefore the relationship between Patient and Consultation is one-to-many. Result Form is also a Child Form which has ID as foreign key. A patient has multiple results at different dates therefore the relationship between Patient and Result is one-to-many.
I created Patient Form and embedded Consultation Form and Result Form in the same Patient Form in grid format. I want to see filtered list of Consultations and Results based on Patient selection. How do I do this?

Thank you for your help

Solomon

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `SelectionChanged` in the Patients grid so when user selects another row, you refresh the data in the second (Consultation) grid properly. And the same applies to the `SelectionChanged` event from your second grid, you would have to handle it too, to populate the third grid (Result).